# Problem with displaying information in a telegram bot with a database

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, mysql-python

when i write to the bot the name of the product i want to see the bot doesn't send me any message

```
def create_message_select_query(ans):
text = ""
for i in ans:
    id = i[0]
    name = i[1]
    icon = i[2]
    text += "id: ""<b>"+ str(id) +"</b> | " + "<b>"+ str(name) +"</b> | " + "<b>"+ str(icon)+"</b> | " "\n"
message = "<b>Received  </b> Information about orders:\n\n"+text
return message
```

@client.on(events.NewMessage(pattern="(?i)/mostra"))
async def delete(event):
try:

```
    sender = await event.get_sender()
    SENDER = sender.id 
    name = re.match(" .*",event.message.text)
    sql_command = "SELECT * FROM unitsprova WHERE name REGEXP (%s) Limit 1;" 
    ans = crsr.execute(sql_command, (name,))
    conn.commit()

    res = crsr.fetchall()

    if ans < 1:
        text = "Order with id {} is not present".format(name)
        await client.send_message(SENDER, text, parse_mode='html')
    else:
        text = create_message_select_query(res) 
        await client.send_message(SENDER, text, parse_mode='html')

except Exception as e: 
    print(e)
    await client.send_message(SENDER, "Something Wrong happened... Check your code!", parse_mode='html')
    return`
```

i tried this way
`@client.on(events.NewMessage(pattern="(?i)/mostra"))
async def delete(event):
try:

```
    sender = await event.get_sender()
    SENDER = sender.id   
    list_of_words = event.message.text.split(" ")
    name = list_of_words[ 1 ]`
```

but the bot only counts the first word I type and not the rest (and I need it to count all the words the user types)

Answer (score 0):

```
@client.on(events.NewMessage(pattern="(?i)/mostra (.*)"))
async def delete(event):
    try:
        sender = await event.get_sender()
        SENDER = sender.id
        name = event.pattern_match.group(1)
        sql_command = "SELECT * FROM unitsprova WHERE name REGEXP (%s) Limit 1;"
        crsr.execute(sql_command, (name,))
        conn.commit()

        res = crsr.fetchall()

        if len(res) < 1:
            text = "Product with name {} is not present".format(name)
            await client.send_message(SENDER, text, parse_mode='html')
        else:
            text = "The product you are looking for is: " + res[0][1]
            await client.send_message(SENDER, text, parse_mode='html')
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        await client.send_message(SENDER, "Something Wrong happened... Check your code!", parse_mode='html')
```

Comment: the code doesn t work

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).